# Append a variable value to the id in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I append a variable value to the end of the id?
I have this code:

```
n = 2;
$("#input_color").spectrum({
             preferredFormat: "rgb",
             color: "#f00"
         });
```

and I want to look like this:

```
n = 2;
$("#input_color2").spectrum({
             preferredFormat: "rgb",
             color: "#f00"
         });
```

Is there any way to merge it like this?

```
n=2;
$("#input_color + 'n'").spectrum({
             preferredFormat: "rgb",
             color: "#f00"
         });
```

Answer (score 4):

Take n variable out of '". If you place variable n inside quots it becomes string n instead of being variable n having value 2.

Final working code:

```
n=2;
$("#input_color" + n).spectrum({
    preferredFormat: "rgb",
    color: "#f00"
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Concatenating a value with a string in JavaScript is quite simple, you use the plus sign (+), but you need to do that ***outside*** of the string:

```
n=2;
$("#input_color" + n).spectrum({
    preferredFormat: "rgb",
    color: "#f00"
});
```

Comment: Ah... That simple! Thanks :)